# Как получить элемент из Dictionary не зная ключа

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Есть словарь типа `Dictionary(Of Integer, ObjectPool)`.

1. Можно ли без цикла `foreach` достать из него объект не зная ключа?
2. Можно ли достать первый или последний объект в словаре не перебирая элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` поэтому можно воспользоваться методами Linq: [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx), [Last](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549138(v=vs.110).aspx) и подобными.

Например:

```
Dim first As ObjectPool = dict.FirstOrDefault().Value
Dim last As ObjectPool = dict.LastOrDefault().Value
```

Но так как не реализуется интерфейс `IList<T>` - обратиться по индексу нельзя.

Comment: Если не трудно приведите решение ибо к сожалению Linq мне совсем не знаком.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, добавил примеры, `Value` в конце нужно так как словарь это `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, поэтому, чтобы получить значение нужно брать `Value` у полученного объекта